# Bootstrap 4 order nested columns

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a problem that the order-[num] is not working because of the left and right side in different col's

Screenshot of view

[image]

[image]

```
<section class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-11">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 mb-3 order-0">
                        order small 1
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 mb-3 order-2">
                        order small 3
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 mb-3 order-1">
                        Ordering as small 2
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3 order-3">
                        ordering as small 4
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3 order-4">
                        ordering as small 5
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

if I placed all col's in one row it created a big white space of the height of place 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of a solution which duplicates the section 3, puts its copy between 2 and the row of 4 and 5, and show/hide section 3 and its copy based on the break point.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <section class="mb-3">
                1
            </section>
            <section class="mb-3 d-none d-md-block">
                3
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <section class="mb-3">
                2
            </section>
            <section class="mb-3 d-md-none">
                copy of 3
            </section>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <section class="mb-3">
                        4
                    </section>            
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <section class="mb-3">
                        5
                    </section>           
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

#### Result

On large screens:
[image]

On small screens:

[image]

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/59x0s17k/1/